# Testing controllers with integration tests

Tags: integration-testing

I work on project that consists from 3 layers: presentation (asp.net mvc) -> business logic -> repository

We test all three parts with unittests.

We plan to add integration tests.
Now we are deciding which part should be tested with them.

We consider next solutions:

- Test controllers, in this case all three parts of the system will be
  involved
- Test business logic, in this case only 2 parts will be involved

I see profit from the second solution in the case if we have few users of our core. For example site, mobile version, commands tool. In this case all clients will use business logic that is well tested.

How do you think what solution is better? 
Could you describe your experience of using integration tests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your first option should be a preference. If you're going to write in-process (i.e. not browser-automation) tests spanning more than one layer, you may as well start as far 'outside' and go through as many layers as you easily can. Starting your tests by calling your controllers should offer insights into and reassurance of how your system behaves given (for example) unexpected or incomplete user input. You can also execute your assertions on the view models returned by your actions, maximising your tests' relevance and coverage.

Answer (score 0):

`business logic -> repository:` Integration Testing is necessary and lots of critical bugs are found here. Many performance related bugs are also found in this layer by identifying bad SQL queries.

`presentation:` There is a mixed reaction to controllers testing. I believe manual or automated testing(by coded UI) of Web page is necessary, but UI testing may not cover all the controllers and business logic. So currently we are writing test for controllers also. Another reason for going for controllers testing is that CodedUI automated tests or Manual Test for UI takes lot of time to execute.

Start by writing Interface Integration tests, then Controllers tests and then coded UI. 
*Manual testing should happen parallel to all of this activity.*